# Threads listening to an event

Tags: c#, multithreading, events

I am writing a program in which I have 'n' number of threads, each named '0', '1', '2', '3',.. 'n-1' respectively. Each of these threads are listening to a button clicked event on the main thread. When the button is clicked, each of the threads must compare the text present in the text box to their names. If the text is the same, the thread must display it, else, it must display "not this".

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public delegate void MyEventHandler(string s);
    public event MyEventHandler m;
    static int ncarr;
    NewClient1[] nc = new NewClient1[5];
    string x;
    Thread[] th = new Thread[5];
    static int tc;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        ncarr = 0;
        tc = 0;
    }

    public void alpha()
    {
        Thread.CurrentThread.Name = (tc-1).ToString();
        nc[tc - 1] = new NewClient1();
        this.m += nc[tc-1].myFunc;
        nc[tc-1].Text = Thread.CurrentThread.Name;
        nc[tc-1].ShowDialog();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (m != null)
        {
            m(textBox1.Text);
        }
        else
        {
            label1.Text = "m is null";
        }
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        th[tc] = new Thread(new ThreadStart(alpha));
        tc++;
        th[tc-1].Start();
    }
}






public partial class NewClient1 : Form
{

    public delegate void SetPrint (string x);

    public NewClient1()
    {
        //if (this.label1.InvokeRequired)
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void myFunc(string x)
    {
        //int i = Int32.Parse(x);
        if (x == Thread.CurrentThread.Name)
        {
            string y = "this is being printed by " + Thread.CurrentThread.Name;
            y += "\n Message received = " + x;
            print(y);
        }
        else
        {
            string y = "not this";
            print(y);  
        }
    }

    public void print(string x)
    {
        if (this.label1.InvokeRequired == true)
        {
            SetPrint d = new SetPrint(print);
            this.Invoke(d, new object[] { x });
        }
        else
        {
            label1.Text = x;
        }
    }
}
```

But when i create multiple threads and even enter '0' in the text box, all threads display "not this".

When i tried debugging, in the line "if (x == Thread.CurrentThread.Name)", the value of Thread.CurrentThread.Name for all the threads is NULL. Please give me a solution to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the "not this" message on all forms because in the below line

```
if (x == Thread.CurrentThread.Name)
```

`Thread.CurrentThread.Name` is `null`.

This is happening because the thread, on which `m(textBox1.Text)` is invoked is the main UI thread and not the thread that you created while instantiating NewClient1 object, which [thread] was named. The main UI thread does not have a Name set and hence it is null.

As a workaround, you can create a property in your NewClient1 class and set it and perform the comparison against this property's value.

```
public string NewClientName { get; set; }
. . .
if (x == NewClientName)
{
   . . . 
}
```

Pictorially, the thread calling can be represented as below

```
+-------------------------+        +--------------------------+
|  Main UI Thread         |        |     NewClient thread     |
|   (Name = null)         |        |     (Name set below)     |
+-------------------------+        +--------------------------+
| on Button Click         |        |                          |
|  > create Thread--------|------> | Create object nc         |
|                         |        | > set this thread's name |
|                         |        |                          |
| on btn2 Click           |        |                          |
|  >invoke mc(txt.Text)   |        |                          |
|   > calls nc.myFunc     |        |                          |
|                         |        |                          |
|//so CurrentThread.Name  |        |                          |
|//is null in this Thread |        |                          |
+-------------------------+        +--------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

this isnt really how threads work.
You need to step through your code to see what is going on. At the end of the day it does what it does because thats how it works.

Basically events are raised on the ui thread so the rest of the execution takes place on that thread. You need to raise the events in the threads you want to process them which means passing control to the other threads in the event handler.

If you did mange to get this working however you would be writing the devils code itself. You are writing something that will have potentially huge side effects because you would have multiple threads writing to things that the ui thread treats as its state potentially whilst it is being used for ui.

you are trying to start ui on threads other than the ui for starters. That is a nono.

You want to use an async worker pattern.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx

is the new school way of doing it.

You should also read about threading and windows forms.I don't do much threading with ui, but when i do i always have to go back and check how it works.

As an aside, if you are creating threads like this you are doing something wrong ;) There will be a far better way to do it that doesn't rely on you getting all the mutable regions / locks and semaphors right. Atomicity is a bitch and she will make you hers. Don't create threads, let .net abstract from that and use higher level appraoches such as async await or task library. Even use the async worker pattern - all far better approaches.

Answer (score 0):

You name the thread that runs 'alpha', this is not necessarily(most likely not) the thread that owns/runs handlers on your NewClient where you check the name.

If you need to identify clients why not give them an identifier property?